# Middleware not populating error when JWT is invalid

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) with the [passport-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt) strategy to authenticate users with a JavaScript Work Token. I need to be able to authorise users based on some metadata so I've set up a custom callback which I'm attaching to the route.

```
router.get('/', auth.loginRequired, function (req, res) {...
```

but I'm having problems calling the function. I've massively simplified it and the strategy as shown below:

```
module.exports = {
  loginRequired: function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, function(err, user, info) {
      if (!err) {
        next()
      } else {
        res.status(401).send
      }
    })(req, res, next)
  }
}
```

The strategy is shown below:

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(payload, done) {
  var user = {firstName: 'Geraint', email: 'test.user@test.co.uk'}
  if (payload) {
    done(null, user)
  } else {
    done('Error', null)
  }
}))
```

When the JWT is valid, the `passport.authenticate` callback is being called as expected with `null` and the user being passed in correctly. When the JWT is invalid though, the error is being passed into the authenticate callback as info. `err` is null and `user` is false.

Why are the parameters getting jumbled if there's an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also worked with this and i got the same output. Passport js work in this way only.

You can change condition and it will work

```
module.exports = {
  loginRequired: function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, function(err, user, info) {
      if (user) {
        next()
      } else {
        res.status(401).send
      }
    })(req, res, next)
  }
}
```

In case of user object present, it will return success otherwise it will return error.

Answer (score 0):

What I do for JWT authentication is:

```
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), function (req, res) {...
```

If the JWT is not valid, then it returns a 401. If it is valid, then it continues into my route.